# Tricks to compare complicated fractions?

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

Solving an integral I find:

\begin{equation}
 I = \int \exp \left\{-N\left ( \epsilon r+\log(1+r) +\frac{rx^2(1-r\tau + \tau r^2 (\tau +1))}{1+r}+\frac{ry^2(-1+r\tau + \tau r^2 (\tau -1))}{1+r}\right) \right \}
\end{equation}

where $-1<\tau<1$, $r>0$ and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$.

However the correct result is:

\begin{equation}
 A = \int \exp \left\{-N\left ( \epsilon r+\log(1+r) +\frac{rx^2}{1+r(1+\tau)}+\frac{ry^2}{1+r(1-\tau)}\right)\right\}
\end{equation}

When I compare the two expressions by plugging in numerical values I do not obtain the same. However when $\tau=0$ I do recover the correct result.

$$\boxed{\frac{rx^2}{1+r(1+\tau)}+\frac{ry^2}{1+r(1-\tau)}} \text{ and } \boxed{\frac{rx^2(1-r\tau + \tau r^2 (\tau +1))}{1+r}+\frac{ry^2(-1+r\tau + \tau r^2 (\tau -1))}{1+r}}$$

I do not see any mistakes in my computation and do not even know how to compare the two answers in a clever way. Is there a smart way to put everything on the same denominator and quickly see which terms are missing?

Any advice or remark is always appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to transform the fractions to see that they are different. You just need to consider them as functions of $\tau$, for example.

Then you will see that forms:
$$
\frac{A}{B+C\tau}\qquad\text{and}\qquad E+F\tau+G\tau^2
$$

cannot be the same.